# Ordenar Objeto Literal en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion donde me ordene las notas de un objeto alumno, esas notas es un objeto litera. Es de un ejercicio de clase.

Esta es mi clase alumno

```
class Alumno {
    constructor(nombre, apellido) {
        // Creamos constructor con el nombre, los apellidos y las notas.
        // Las asignamos a unas variables privadas.
        this._nombre = nombre || 'Sin nombre',
            this._apellido = apellido || 'Sin apellido',
            this._Notas = {
                Matematicas: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Lengua: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Fisica: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Ingles: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Musica: generaAleatorio(0, 10)
            };
        // Para poder acceder a esas variables privadas, tenemos que crearnos 
        // unas funciones get/set que puedan modificarlas
        this.getNombre = function() { // Devolvemos el nombre de la variable privada
            return this._nombre;
        }
        this.setNombre = function(nombre) {
            this._nombre = nombre; // Almacenamos en el nombre la variable privada
        }
        this.getApellido = function() { // Devolvemos el nombre de la variable privada
            return this._apellido;
        }
        this.setApellido = function(apellido) {
            this._apellido = apellido; // Almacenamos en el nombre la variable privada
        }

        this.getNotas = function() { // Devolvemos el nombre de la variable privada
            return this._Notas;
        }
        this.setNotas = function(Notas) {
            this._Notas = Notas; // Almacenamos en el nombre la variable privada
            Object.keys(this._Notas).map(function(key) {
                if (this._Notas[key] < 0) {
                    this._Notas = 0;
                }
                if (this._Notas[key] > 10) {
                    this._Notas = 10;
                }

            });

        }

    }

}


function generaAleatorio(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

}
```

En otro archivo llamado metodos hago las funciones. Para que me muestre las notas he hecho unna funcion con Object.keys, pero a la hora de hacer también el sort me da fallo.

```
function ordenarNotas(Alumno, boolean) {
    boolean = true;
    if (boolean) {
        Object.keys(Alumno.getNotas()).map(function(key) {
            Alumno.getNotas().sort(function(a, b) {
                return b - a;
            });
            return " " + key + ": " + Alumno.getNotas()[key];
        });
    }
    if (boolean = false) {
        Object.keys(Alumno.getNotas()).map(function(key) { return " " + key + ": " + Alumno.getNotas()[key]; });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función `ordenarNotas` tiene los siguientes detalles:

- `Alumno.getNotas().sort` no es válido, ya que este método devuelve un objeto.
- La idea de hacer `map` y dentro de este hacer `sort` (*si funcionara*) sería poco eficiente.
- En ningún momento devuelves un resultado

### Solución:

Una forma de obtener el resultado que buscas sería:

- Obtenemos las notas del alumno (`alumno.getNotas() ==> object`)
- Obtenemos las claves del objeto `notas` (`Object.keys(object) ==> array`)
- Por cada clave en el arreglo creamos un arreglo de la clave y su valor (`array.map(key => [key, notas[key]]) ==> array(array(key, value), ...)`)
- Ordenamos el arreglo de arreglos en base a valor (`array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])`)
- Finalmente solo queda recorrer el arreglo de arreglos para obtener, por ejemplo, una cadena con la lista de materias ordenadas (`array.reduce((acc, val) => acc += val[0] + ': ' + val[1] + '\n', '')`)

#### Ejemplo:

```
function ordenarNotas(alumno, boolean = true) {
  let notas = alumno.getNotas();
  if (boolean) {
    return Object.keys(notas)
      .map(key => [key, notas[key]])
      .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
      .reduce((acc, val) => acc += val[0] + ': ' + val[1] + '\n', '')
  }
  return Object.keys(notas).reduce((acc, key) => acc += key + ': ' + notas[key] + '\n', '')
}
```

#### Demo:

```js
class Alumno {
  constructor(nombre, apellido) {
    // Creamos constructor con el nombre, los apellidos y las notas.
    // Las asignamos a unas variables privadas.
    this._nombre = nombre || 'Sin nombre',
      this._apellido = apellido || 'Sin apellido',
      this._Notas = {
        Matematicas: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
        Lengua: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
        Fisica: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
        Ingles: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
        Musica: generaAleatorio(0, 10)
      };
    // Para poder acceder a esas variables privadas, tenemos que crearnos 
    // unas funciones get/set que puedan modificarlas
    this.getNombre = function() { // Devolvemos el nombre de la variable privada
      return this._nombre;
    }
    this.setNombre = function(nombre) {
      this._nombre = nombre; // Almacenamos en el nombre la variable privada
    }
    this.getApellido = function() { // Devolvemos el nombre de la variable privada
      return this._apellido;
    }
    this.setApellido = function(apellido) {
      this._apellido = apellido; // Almacenamos en el nombre la variable privada
    }

    this.getNotas = function() { // Devolvemos el nombre de la variable privada
      return this._Notas;
    }
    this.setNotas = function(Notas) {
      this._Notas = Notas; // Almacenamos en el nombre la variable privada
      Object.keys(this._Notas).map(function(key) {
        if (this._Notas[key] < 0) {
          this._Notas = 0;
        }
        if (this._Notas[key] > 10) {
          this._Notas = 10;
        }

      });
    }
  }
}

function generaAleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function ordenarNotas(alumno, boolean = true) {
  let notas = alumno.getNotas();
  if (boolean) {
    return Object.keys(notas)
      .map(key => [key, notas[key]])
      .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
      .reduce((acc, val) => acc += val[0] + ': ' + val[1] + '\n', '')
  }
  return Object.keys(notas).reduce((acc, key) => acc += key + ': ' + notas[key] + '\n', '')
}

let alumno = new Alumno('John', 'Doe');
console.log(ordenarNotas(alumno));
```